# Make invisible object visible with typed word

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to make an invisible object visible when I type the word I chose in my game, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Making an invisible object visible is generally easy — just start with its [renderer](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer.html) disabled and then enable it for example.

```
GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = true;
```

(This may vary slightly for e.g. a sprite.)

For the second part, assuming you mean something like a cheat code where the game is accepting normal control input without anything like an input field, but pressing a specific combination of keys will activate a secret function, I think something like this should work:

```
string cheatCode = “magiceye”;
int index=0;

void Update() 
{
    foreach(char c in Input.inputString) {
        if( c == cheatCode[index] )
            index++;
        else
            index=0; // Reset if a wrong key is typed

        if( index == cheatCode.Length ) {
            RevealInvisibleObject(); // Full cheat code was entered uninterrupted
            index=0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it works thank you so much my hero

Comment: If you wanted to avoid something like capslock preventing the code from working due to case sensitivity, you could use `if( Char.ToLower(c) == cheatCode[index] )`